# Java GlassFish does not exist

Tags: netbeans-8.2, glassfish

Estoy intentando descargar glassfish para tener habilitado el java web, pero al momento de descargar la `versión 4.1.1` me dice esto

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No estoy al tanto de si está obsoleto o qué me estoy saltando.

Comment: Como sugerencia (no para resolver la pregunta): Yo no usaría una ruta que incluya nombres de carpetas con espacios. En general, es una mala idea en productos que corran sobre Java.

Answer (score 0):

Verifica que dentro de la carpeta se encuentren los archivos correspondientes a GlassFish.

[![Si no están dentro de esta manera entonces trata de mover la carpeta a tu disco raiz. En mi caso el Disco C.
][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jjfqe.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jjfqe.png)

Si no funciona lo anterior trata de volver a descargar GlassFish desde otra fuente, puede que el archivo presente errores. Me ha pasado que viene dañado el archivo, recién lo cambio y ya funciona el servidor.